# Basic Conditional Operator

Tags: c, conditional-statements, operators

I have tried using a conditional operator to reduce the lines of code in the following C Program, however, I'm not getting the desired result.

*Objective - To set the value of `x` to `50` if `y > 7` else set it to `25`*

```
#include <stdio.h> // Conditional Operator

int main()
{
    int x, y;

    printf("Enter x: ", x);

    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter y: ", y);

    scanf("%d", &y);

    if (x = y > 7 ? 25 : 50)
    { 
        printf("Value of x: %d", x);
    }  
    else
    {
        printf("Failed\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `x = (y > 7 ? 50 : 25)`. That is, need parentheses and the ternery values need to be reversed. Also, what is the point of `scanf("%d",&x);` if you then set it to something else before ever using it again?

Comment: Also, why do you think you might ever print "Failed"?  And you should include a newline in the code that prints `x`, and you should print `x` unconditionally.  And, as a general rule, using a conditional operator to try and reduce the number of lines is not a particularly good idea — your goal should be clarity of the code, so there is no chance of you and the compiler misunderstanding each other.

Comment: Note that `printf("Enter y: ", y);` has one too many arguments to `printf()`.  Likewise for the other prompt, though there's little point in prompting for `x` since you assign to it instead of ever using the entered value.  And strictly, you should check that the calls to `scanf()` are successful (return `1`) so that you know the user typed an integer value and not a word or some other non-numeric data.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to reset the value of x from an already set value to 25 or 50 based on the condition of y

Comment: Why would you want to input `x` if you'll just set it later. Also, why that `if` statement?
It should be only `x=(y > 7 ? 25 : 50)`. Also, do you really need to print the `else` part?

Comment: What output are you getting?  What output are you expecting?  This information should be in the question.

Comment: I just started learning how to code, so I'm still new and this was my first question on Stackoverflow so I do apologise for the bad formatting of the question.

Comment: @SouvikDatta After considering the comments, do you now get the desired result?

Comment: Yes @kiranBiradar Thank You!

Comment: Your question has just proven why `?:` should be generally avoided. A better way to write this code is `if(y > 7) x=50 else x=25;` More readable and same machine code if not better. `?:` also comes with some subtle quirks of integer promotion that could lead to slower code or bugs.

Comment: @kaylum > has higher precedence than ?: which has higher precedence than =. So the parenthesis isn't needed (but good practice anyway).

Comment: @kaylum Why do you think it needs  parentheses? It's not correct

Comment: @Lundin "but good practice anyway" I disagree. Code like: `x = y > 7 ? 50 : 25;`  needs no parenthesis. When used if an if-condition (which should be avoid anyway, IMO) then it's good practice to put parenthesis but not where suggested by kaylum. When it would be: `if ((x = y > 7 ? 50 : 25))`

Comment: @4386427 Even C veterans struggle to get precedence right... so anyone who has a doubt about the order should use parenthesis and there's no harm in it. The classic `if(reg&mask == val)` bug comes to mind, even Dennis Ritchie called this one a language design mistake. And many coding standards enforce parenthesis around all sub-expressions... though the same coding standards likely also ban assignment in conditions, which is indeed dangerous practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Objective - To set the value of x to 50 if y > 7 else set it to 25

Then you have swapped the values here:

```
y > 7 ? 25 : 50
        ^^   ^^
         wrong
```

It  has to be:

```
y > 7 ? 50 : 25
```

The reason is:

```
y > 7 ? 50 : 25
\---/    |    |
  |      |    -----> Result if condition is FALSE
  |      |
  |      ---> Result if condition TRUE
  |
condition
```

**Other notes**

1. Why do you take x as input when you always overwrite it with 50 or 25?
2. Always check the return value from `scanf`
3. The `else` part of your `if` statement can't be reached. So it can be deleted.
4. `printf("Enter y: ",y);` is wrong. You don't print `y`. So delete `,y`

So simply do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x,y;

    printf("Enter y: ");

    if (scanf("%d",&y) != 1)
    {
        puts("wrong input");
        return 0;
    }

    x = y > 7 ? 50 : 25;
    printf("Value of x: %d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

**Final note**

Your code has this line:

```
if (x = y > 7 ? 25 : 50)
```

Here you do an assignment to `x` inside the `if` condition and the assigned value is then used as condition for the `if`.

While it's perfectly legal C code, most programmers consider it bad. The reason is that it easy to confuse with

```
if (x == y > 7 ? 25 : 50)
      ^^
    Did you really want a compare!?
```

In general it's better to avoid assignments in the `if` condition, i.e. you could have done:

```
x = y > 7 ? 25 : 50;
if (x)
```

instead. As another benefit of this, it's also much more clear that the `else` part can't be reached.